# Unpacking in a for loop twice

Tags: python

I am trying to find the last iteration in a loop so that I can skip it. This is not ideal I'm aware, however my issue is separate.

I am new to python, but if I'm not mistaken, this for loop is in unpacking the variable `letter`. This makes the second run through of the for loop empty or in some sense broken. If my understanding here is in anyway incorrect, feel free to comment or edit.

```
this_iteration = 0
for [x, y, dx, dy, r], letter in letters_positions:
    last_iteration = this_iteration
    this_iteration += 1
this_iteration = 0

for [x, y, dx, dy, r], letter in letters_positions:
    if this_iteration == last_iteration:
        continue
    this_iteration += 1
```

I tried unsuccessfully passing this in the second for loop, but the second for loop still does not run.

```
for letter in letters_positions:
```

Is there a way for me to repack the variables together for a second run through the loop?

**UPDATE:** This is CairoSVG, not my own code, but I'll try to post more context the best I can. letters_positions is taken from an svg file. The important two lines that precede my code are the following.

```
from .helpers import distance, normalize, point_angle, zip_letters

letters_positions = zip_letters(x, y, dx, dy, rotate, node.text)
```

Original CairoSVG code can be found on github here.

https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/blob/master/cairosvg/text.py

Comment: Can you post the contents of `letters_positions`

Comment: Could you state precisely what happens when you applied the code you tried? The full error I mean.

Comment: @BAH Update posted

Comment: @Gabriel no error, however the loop doesn't run, implying that there's nothing to iterate now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (example):

```
this_iteration = 0
letters_positions = list(letters_positions)

for [x, y, dx, dy, r], letter in letters_positions:
    last_iteration = this_iteration
    this_iteration += 1
this_iteration = 0

for [x, y, dx, dy, r], letter in letters_positions:
    if this_iteration == last_iteration:
        continue
    this_iteration += 1
```

From `helpers.py` in the [github link](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/blob/master/cairosvg/helpers.py) you posted:

```
# Incidentally, they say that this method returns a list with the current letter's positions.
# This isn't true - it is returning a generator.
# To return a list, the outermost parenthesis need to be replaced with square brackets,
#    or by simply adding list before the parenthesis
# i.e. [...] or list(...)
def zip_letters(xl, yl, dxl, dyl, rl, word):
    """Returns a list with the current letter's positions (x, y and rotation).
    E.g.: for letter 'L' with positions x = 10, y = 20 and rotation = 30:
    >>> [[10, 20, 30], 'L']
    Store the last value of each position and pop the first one in order to
    avoid setting an x,y or rotation value that have already been used.
    """
    # Notice the parenthesis below - this is a generator that gets exhausted after one iteration
    return (
        ([pl.pop(0) if pl else None for pl in (xl, yl, dxl, dyl, rl)], char)
        for char in word)
```

Thus, you empty it after the first iteration. Create a list or some other data structure out of it `letters_positions = list(letters_positions)`, and then you can loop over it as many times as you'd like.

Comment: I could not figure out how to get your suggests to work, I was able to get this to work by re declaring letters_positions. What I tried was `letters_positions = list(letters_positions)` and `for letter in letters_positions:`, can you post an example of the code after declaring `letters_positions` in a list?

Answer (score 0):

`letters_positions` is a sequence.  If you don't want to iterate over the final element, do iterate over `letters_positions[:-1]`

EDIT: if you're using Python3, you might have to call `list` on `letters_positions` first